# How to utilize 2d/3d Graphics Acceleration on a Single Board Computer

Tags: graphics, embedded, hardware-acceleration

This may be a somewhat silly question, but if you are working with a single board computer that boasts that it has 2d/3d graphics acceleration, what does this actually mean?

If it supports DirectX or OpenGL obviously I could just use that framework, but I am not familiar with working from this end of things.  I do not know if that means that it is capable of having those libraries included into the OS or if it just means that it does certain kinds of math more quickly (either by default or through some other process)

Any clarification on what this means or locations of resources I could use on such would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On embedded system's, 2D/3D Graphics Acceleration could mean a lot of things. For instance, that framebuffer operations are accelerated through DirectFB, or that OpenGL ES is supported.

The fact is that the manufacturer of the board usually provides these libraries since the *acceleration of the graphics* itself is deeply connected to the hardware.

It's best to get in touch with your manufacturer and ask which graphics libraries they support that are hardware accelerated.

Comment: It's also the manufacturer of the board who chooses which features of DirectFB/OpenGL/whatever can/should be hardware accelerated.

Comment: Thanks, I've sent off e-mails to the ones that I was looking at to find out the specifics.  I thought there was some standard terminology or method I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two very important features of 2D/3D graphics cards:

1. Take a load away from the CPU
2. Process that load much faster than the CPU can do because it has a special instruction set that was designed explicitly for calculations that are common in graphics (e.g. transformations)

Sometimes other jobs are passed on to the GPU because a job requires calculations that fit very good to the instructions of the GPU. E.g. a physics library requires lots of matrix calculation so a GPU could be used to do that. [NVIDIA made PHYSIX](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_new.html) to do exactly that. [See this FAQ also](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_faq.html)

Answer (score 0):

The minumum a graphics display required is to allow the setting of the state (colour) of individual pixels.  This allows you to render any image within the resolution and colour depth of the display, but for complex drawing tasks and very high resolution displays this would be very slow.

*Graphics acceleration* refers to any graphics processing function off-loaded to hardware.  At its simplest this may mean the drawing and filling of graphics primitives such as lines, and polygons, and 'blitting' - the moving of blocks of pixels from one location to another.  Technically *graphics acceleration* has been largely replaced by *graphics processors (GPUs)*, though the affect is the same - faster graphics.  GPUs are more flexible since a hardware accelerator can accelerate only the set of operations they are hard wrired to perform, which may benefit some applications more than others.

Modern GPU graphics hardware performs far higher level graphics processing.  It is also possible to use the GPU to perform more general purpose matrix computation tasks using interfaces such as Nvidia's CUDA, which can then accelerate computational tasks other than graphics but which require teh same kind of mathematical operations.

The Wikipedia "Graphics processing unit" article has a [history of Graphics Accelerators and GPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit#History)